# Unable to get NSMutableArray with multiple Object from UserDefaults in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, nsuserdefaults

I am having custom class which stores the login information of the user.
App can have multiple users logged in at a time.

This is how I am storing the logged in users data to UserDefaults.

```
let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard
        let decoded = userDefaults.data(forKey: "CPContactInfo")

        if userDefaults.object(forKey: "CPContactInfo") != nil {
            let decodedTeams = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: decoded!) as! NSMutableArray
                arrayOfArray.add(qidInfo)
            }
        } else {
            print("userdefault not exist")
            arrayOfArray.add(qidInfo)
        }
        addQID(qid_info: arrayOfArray)
```

Where `qidInfo` is custom object of class `QBM_CPContactInfo` which I store it in array, 
at first I checked if UserDefault is present or not for given key at very first time, then added my `qidInfo` object into the array `arrayOfArray` and then that array is saved into UserDefault by calling function `addQID(qid_info: arrayOfArray)`

This is how my `addQID` function is,

```
func addQID(qid_info: NSMutableArray) {
        let userDefaults = UserDefaults()
        let encodedData: Data = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: qid_info)
        userDefaults.set(encodedData, forKey: "CPContactInfo")
        userDefaults.synchronize()
    }
```

After this when I add second logged in details it executes the

```
if userDefaults.object(forKey: "CPContactInfo") != nil
```

perfectly.

When I try to retrieve data from UserDefaults as below,

```
let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard
        let decoded = userDefaults.data(forKey: "CPContactInfo")
        if userDefaults.object(forKey: "CPContactInfo") != nil {
            let decodedTeams = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: decoded!) as! NSMutableArray
            print(decodedTeams)
            qid_info = decodedTeams.object(at: 0) as! QBM_CPContactInfo
            print(qid_info?.qidEmail)
        }
```

it gives me only one object in return for `decodedTeams` as NSMutableArray, but actually I have added two items in NSMutableArray.

Can any one tell me whats I am doing wrong.

further I need to compare the email of user selected which is in 
`let title = action.title` along with `qid_info?.qidEmail.`

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You only add to `arrayOfArray` if `CPContactInfo` is not stored in `UserDefaults`?  Don't you want to retrieve the array and then always add the entry regardless of whether its already stored or not?

Comment: Yes, I always want to add the entry. only if element is already present, I won't add. but I know my this condition will not work because I am not able to login for already logged in. so every time login is success I want to append element into arrayOfArray and then that array into UserDefaults

Comment: Every time when I retrieve the UserDefaults at line let decodedTeams = `NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: decoded!) as! NSMutableArray` it gives count as 1 item only, but actually I have added 2 into it.

Comment: Yeah I think my previous observations were incorrect.  OK, so what about this statement: `if decodedTeams == qidInfo`?  Is this supposed to be comparing two instances of `NSMutableArray`?

Comment: Yes, this is just I added for my checking, any how that if condition will never get execute. I have other method which executes previously to check same login user. I have edited the code now.

Comment: Don’t use `NSMutable...` collection types in Swift. I strongly doubt that you get a `NSMutableArray` just by downcasting the type. And checking for `nil` rather than using optional bindings is also pretty *objective-c-ish*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have the following approach.

`let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard
        let decoded = userDefaults.data(forKey: "CPContactInfo")
        if userDefaults.object(forKey: "CPContactInfo") != nil {
            let decodedTeams = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: decoded!) as! Array<QBM_CPContactInfo>
            arrayOfArray = decodedTeams
            arrayOfArray.append(qidInfo)
        } else {
            arrayOfArray.append(qidInfo)
        }
        addQID(qid_info: arrayOfArray)`

Here, first, get the saved Array from defaults in a temporary array and copy that temporary array in your existing array.
Then append new elements into it and save the updated array for the same key.

Comment: :- Thanks. Followed the approach and solve my issue.